# Google for Work not connected to Google Developers Console

Tags: google-apps

We have been using Google for Work for years now and have a domain setup thru godaddy. We got it so we would have a descent email server without having to worry about it. I then signed up for the Google Developers Console to expand the options we have available and move our local apache/php business software to the cloud. I correctly setup a project with a lamp instance which also works great.

Problem is I cant add projects thru the
https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0
it returns

> Error Developers Console has not been activated for your account. 
>   Your account may be suspended or disabled.  If you are a Google Apps
>   user, ask your domain administrator to enable Apphosting Admin on your
>   account.

But from here I can add new projects
https://code.google.com/apis/console

If I goto the Google for Work console App Engine apps it says

> No services have been installed.
>   Add services to your domain

I click the link to add the service
and goto the Other Services

> Google App Engine Provide existing Google App Engine services to your
>   users. 
>   Enter App ID:*

What is the App ID? I have already authorized the domain we are using for the services.

If I goto Google for Work Domain admin and try to add the other domain we have it says

> We are sorry, but you do not have access to Webmaster tool. Please log
>   in to your Admin Console to enable Webmaster tool. Learn more

Its also adding the domain name to the Project ID: which causes this error in the SDK console

> :\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute ssh
>   example.com:api-project-??????? --zone us-central1-a ERROR:
>   (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch instance:
>    - Invalid value 'example.com:api-project-???????'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-z](? z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?'

Im really confused

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin.google.com, login with our organisation account, go to **Apps** -> **Additional Google Services** -> Enable the services you need.

[image]